# Very Low Wi-Fi Performance

Tags: networking, wifi, performance

I've got a problem, i realized that my Wi-Fi connection on RaspberryPI 3 its very slow (that's not normal)

I installed speedtest-cli to test speed of internet.

And this is the result:

> Download: 23,76Mbps (its 2,96Mb/s in real)
>   Upload: 4,02Mbps (its 502Kb/s in real)

I launched also SpeedTest from my Android phone and here is the result:

> Download: 74,32Mbps (its 9,25Mb/s in real)
>   Upload: 4,24Mbps (its 520kb/s in real)

Note: i've runned SpeedTest in almost the same position. (Devices been very close)

I noticed that after executing "iwconfig wlan0" command Bitrate is 72Mbps and this is too small (its about 5Mb/s in real), for samba, plex etc...

I buyed TP-Link Wr823n (im waiting for delivery), this adapter should allow me to get BitRate up to 300Mb/s (so i could get maximum performance of my router)

Did i make right decision, or its just waste of money? Unfortunatly i cannot connect my RPI via Wired connection

And i'm trying to get Maximum performance of file transfering etc..
Should i do anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try disabling IPv6 and then retrying the speed test. The reason I suggest this is because I faced similar issues between my router and my Pi when it came to IPv6. When I turned it off it improved my speeds for downloads/uploads.

Check to see if you have any IPv6 sockets open using

```
netstat -lnpt
```

If you wish to turn off IPv6:

```
sudo su
echo "#disable ipv6" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

I would recommend trying this before you use your new TP-Link Wr823n and comparing the speeds. Reverting back to IPv6, trying out the TP-Link Wr823n and then deciding if you need it or not. Hope this is of help.